# Determine points of discontinuity for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{x/(1-x)}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

My attempt: We are give with  $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{x/(1-x)}}$. Let $h(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$. Then we know that $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ are discontinous at $x=0$ and $x=1$ respectively. Checking continuity in $f(x)$ at those values, we observe that $f(x)$ is not defined when $x=0$. Hence the point of dicountinuity is $x=0$ and the discontinuity is of second kind.

This approach was motivated by the fact that if $g(x)$ is continous at $x=x_0$ then $h(g(x))$ must also be continous at $x=x_0$.

Based on this example, I'd like to know that in general if we are given with two functions $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ that are discontinous at $x=x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ then will their compositions $f_1(x)=h(g(x))$ and $f_2(x)=g(h(x))$ be discontinous only at those values of $x$ which lie in the set $\{x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

Let $f(x)=\mathbf{1}_{\geq 1}(x)$ and $g(x)=2\mathbf{1}_{>2}(x)+\mathbf{1}_{\leq2}(x)$

Then:

$$f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = 1\;\; \forall x$$